# What does [^.]* mean in regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get 482.75 from the following text: `<span id="yfs_l84_aapl">482.75</span>`

The regex I used is: `regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_[^.]*">(.+?)</span>'` and it worked.

But the thing that I do not understand is why [^.]* can match aapl here? My understanding is that . means any character except a newline; and ^ means negator. So [^.] should be newline and [^.]* should be any number of new lines. However this theory is contrary to real world implementation.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

---

The python code I used:

```
import urllib
import re 
htmlfile = urllib.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AAPL&ql=0")
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_[^.]*">(.+?)</span>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
price = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)
print "the price of of aapl is", price[0]
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Within the `[]` the `.` means just a dot. And the leading `^` means "anything but ...".

So `[^.]*` matches zero or more non-dots.

Comment: The Python documentation even says so explictly: [Special characters lose their special meaning inside sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Comment: that doesn't ans why it matches `aapl`

Comment: @Anirudh: Yes it does.

Answer (score 4):

. dot in a character-matcher just means dot, literally.

Different syntax and special-characters (- dash for range, ^ for negation) apply inside a character-matching specification. Other pattern syntaxes do not apply.