# What does `[^<]*` mean in regular expressions?

Tags: regex, perl

I found some Perl code that uses `[^<]*` in a regular expression. What is the meaning of this?

Comment: oh, sorry,I hate this kind of lazy questions: please, see [quick regex manual](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm)

Comment: I did research before posting,  but whenever I try typing `[^<]*` into a search engine, it returns 0 results, maybe because search engines aren't designed to look for such things. I know what `[]`, `^`, and `*` do, but together with the `<` am not sure if `<` is just a symbol like `ABCD` or if it gives a special meaning here.

Comment: it match ZERO characters? :)

Comment: here [example](http://rubular.com/r/zOISCy1YV9)

Comment: As @aelor said, you could use http://regex101.com/ for other regexes in future. It will show you a verbose explanation on the right. And gaussblurinc... Regex are not that trivial for beginners so please... calm down, go to meta so or somewhere to express your frustration. thx.

Comment: Related [What does \[^.\]* mean in regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089800/what-does-mean-in-regular-expression). I don't close as dup, because that has the Python tag. But Python and Perl does not differ in that point.

Answer (score 4):

Match 0 or more chars that are NOT `<` char.

`^` when it is first inside `[]` inverts class definition.

Answer (score 1):

It basically means that 0 or more any chars that are not the char <

`*` means 0 or more

`^` inverts a character class

`<` is the char

`[]` is the class

Comment: `^` inverts a character class, when it is the first character inside. Outside a char class it has a different meaning. **It does not mean not**.

Answer (score 1):

Match 0 or more chars that are NOT basically `<` character

```
* means 0 or more
[] is the class on it
```